# Binding to static property in embedded class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return "Prop1";
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public static string Property2
        {
            get
            {
                return "Prop2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="provider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Class1}"/>
```

This one works:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource provider},Path=Property1}" />
```

But this one doesn't:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource provider},Path=Class2.Property2}" />
```

How can I bind to `Class2.Property2`?

Comment: `Class2.Property2` is not a valid property path, because `Class2` is not a property of `Class1`.

Comment: "is not a valid property path" 
It's clear. How correctly to receive property2?

Comment: Why don't you bind to the static property directly? `<Button Content="{x:Static local:Class1+Class2.Property2}" />`

Comment: While that works, it's not actually a Binding. Which would look like this: `Content="{Binding Path=(local:Class1+Class2.Property2)}"`

Comment: @Clemens: True. The comment should have read "why don't you *set* ...". But it's unclear whether the OP acually needs a binding in this case since he wants to display the value of a static read-only property that will never change.